# What does the best die look like?

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization, recreational-mathematics

Intransitive dice have attracted a lot of attention - especially in the context of recreational math - since their introduction by Efron in the 1960s. More recently, there has been work studying intransitivity for *random* dice. See, for instance, the Polymath paper ["The probability that a random triple of dice is transitive"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.16156).

This recent work on intransitivty for random dice motivates us to look at the tournament on the set of *all* dice we get from considering the "beats" relation.

Here a die is a nondecreasing sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ of integers from $[n] = \{1,...,n\}$ with sum $n(n+1)/2$. (This is the "multiset" model of dice, which is probably the most natural one.) We say one die *beats* another if on average it rolls a higher number. (Technically we have to deal with ties as well, but that is not a big issue.)

**Question**: Fix $n$, and consider the tournament with vertices the dice and with edges determined by the beats relation. (Technically because of ties we only get a *partial* tournament, but anyways we get some digraph.) What is the "best" die according to this tournament of dice? Can we say anything about the "shape" of this optimal die (as $n\to\infty$, say)?

Note that when we have a nontransitive tournament there is not a clear "best" player, but there are various ways to measure who is the best that have been considered. The most naive thing is just to choose the player who won the most. But there are other ranking methods, such as the so-called "Kendall-Wei method," which reward players more for beating good players: see, e.g., [Ranking the Players in a Round Robin Tournament](https://doi.org/10.2307/1402170) by H.A. David.

Comment: Notice that in what I discussed above, die $\alpha$ having a huge advantage over die $\beta$ is not considered any better than die $\alpha$ having a .01% advantage over die $\beta$. Depending on the context this could be a reasonable assumption or not. In the discussion of the "best die" in some small colleciton of dice in the Wiki page on intransitive dice (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_dice), they consider how dominant an advantage each die has over the other dice (which again is different from what I am describing).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s very open ended (many possible approaches, as OP notes) and shows no details of what OP’s already tried (if anything).  It’d be a very nice question for a different context — a fun problem to discuss at the departmental happy hour, or a starting point for a student research project — but as a MathOverflow question, it just feels like a fishing expedition.

Comment: For small $n$ it seems to be extremist but not maximally so. From $n=7$ this uses numerical rather than symbolic calculation of the eigenvector. Winners for $4 \le n \le 10$ are (1, 3, 3, 3), (1, 1, 4, 4, 5), (1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6), (1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 7), (1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8), (1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9), (1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9, 10).

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: Fair enough! This question is indeed more just "fun speculation" than anything that came up in my serious research program...